Why is Windows 10 Game Bar sound recording quality is atrocious and what can be done to fix it?
I want to record my screen while I'm doing a tutoring lesson involving switching between multiple apps and talking in the microphone.
With OBS Studio, sound recording is great by default - I hear basically nothing but my voice which is at a normal level.
But with Windows Game Bar, I hear massive amounts of background noise and my voice is ridiculously loud. It's as if by default the sound recording level was ultra high yet I can't find a setting anywhere to change that.
Any suggestion?

What mic are you recording from? Is Gamebar recording from the same mic OBS is recording from?

@music2myear sudotack st-800, yes same mic

That's good but not quite what I'm asking: Have you confirmed the INPUT you're recording from in the Game Bar is the same you're recording from in OBS?

Yes that's what I meant, same mic set as input in settings of both apps.

What are the mic and recording settings for your system and the apps? Also, please add this information to your question so people don't need to read through the comments to fully comprehend your problem.

Thank you @music2myear but I ended up recording my screen with OBS (didn't know that was so easy to do). Should I delete the question?

You can delete it, or you could post an answer saying that you didn't figure out how to correct the audio issues in the Xbox Game Bar but you learned how easy it was to record the screen in OBS and so just used that, and mark that as the answer. Your question is reasonably well presented, though you could perhaps edit it to say your primary requirement is to just get a good screen recording with mic audio, so that we can more clearly see the "workaround" is actually a good and complete solution. Then you get a good question, good answer, and good points for it.

Will do that now, thanks @music2myear

I wasn't able to solve the issue with Game Bar however I found out that screen recording with OBS Studio is a breeze: just select "Display Capture" as the source and hit "Start Recording": voilà.
And the sound is perfect too.
